# Angular-How to translate to other language without affecting Application language

Tags: html, angular, ngx-translate

I have a dialog with content and an toggle for the user to choose between 2 languges. When user switches between these languages, only the content of the dialog has to change, without affecting the application langauge.

Have tried creating a pipe which accepts language, but it changes my entire application language. I am expecting only the language of the dailog to change.
Note: I am using Angular 14.